# ReactJS - build virtual dom only and then mount to an existing DOM node rendered from server

Tags: reactjs, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering

I am building a server-side rendering utility for react. I am not using `ReactDOMServer` and its associated `renderToString` method. Instead, I am rendering the app to a lightweight server-side DOM. Individual components can load data asynchronously (via AJAX, setTimeout, etc) and when all of the promises are resolved, I send the final HTML string to the browser. The async data is stored on a javascript variable named `INLINE_CACHE` for use in the client. **This part works flawlessly.**

On the client, the app component mounts to the document. When the child components go to load data, my data controller can see the `INLINE_CACHE` and resolve the promises immediately. **This part works too**.

When each promise is resolved, I call `setState` with the data which triggers a re-render. My problem is that even though the promises are resolved immediately, they are still resolved asynchronously per the A+ spec. This means that the initial render does not have all of the data it needs. A split second later (next tick, if you will), the data is there and a re-render occurs. **But since the initial render doesn't match the existing markup from the server (and the associated checksum), react complains... rightfully so**.

What I need to do is somehow render the app component in a detached DOM node (or virtual DOM only), wait for all promises to resolve, and then mount the node to the document. The goal is that react will attempt to reuse the existing markup rendered from the server. I know how to generate checksums and so forth - that's not the problem. I just need react to render my app in memory until I tell it to mount to the real DOM - at which point a diff occurs. Is this possible with React?